# Reset Android textview maxlines

Tags: android, textview

I want to make a TextView that is collapsable by user's touch.
When the TextView collapsed, I set `textView.setMaxLines(4);`.
How to I clear this state in my expand method?
I can only think of call `setMaxLines()` with a value large number like **10000**.

Are there better ways to implement this?

Comment: just tried, 0 will hide the textview, -1 crash the app

Comment: It's weird that setting -1 crashes the app when `getMaxLines()` itself returns -1

Answer (score 130):

Actually, the way android platform does that is by setting the MaxLine to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

also, if you are using Ellipsize, don't forget to set to null.

```
textView.setEllipsize(null);
```

just check how the android framework do just that ;) watch the setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

```
private void applySingleLine(boolean singleLine, boolean applyTransformation) {
    mSingleLine = singleLine;
    if (singleLine) {
        setLines(1);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        if (applyTransformation) {
            setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
       } else {
            setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
            if (applyTransformation) {
                 setTransformationMethod(null);
        }
       }
     }
```

You can find this in the source code of Android Open Source Project (AOSP)

https://source.android.com/source/downloading

If you do not want to download the source, you can view the source on a mirror like this one at github.

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java

Comment: Just in case someone bumps into this like I did:
1) I wouldn't use setLines in the first part but use setMaxLines(1) instead.
2) The setEllipsize to null is very important in order to make the view expand in older android versions
3) getLineCount (from the other answer) isn't very reliable from my experience.

Comment: @Valdemar can you share with us how did you get to this beautiful piece of code?

Comment: thnaks @Raanan. getLineCount() doesn`t work in my side, MAX_VALUE work perfectly..

Comment: @IsralBustami Cool, happy to see that a comment from 2013 is still helpful. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this (**infoView.getLineCount()**):

```
public void onMoreClick(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    if(!moreSwitcher) {
        infoView.setMaxLines(infoView.getLineCount());
        infoView.setLines(infoView.getLineCount());
        moreSwitcher = true;
        btn.setText(R.string.collapse);
    }else{
        infoView.setMaxLines(5);
        infoView.setLines(5);
        moreSwitcher = false;
        btn.setText(R.string.expand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for `setLines` (for which doesn't work `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: The most correct way to reset `setLines()` is to call `setMinLines(0)` and then `setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` (this does not work if `scrollHorizontally` is set to true)

Comment: can we apply animation same time