# How to disable the TextView maxLines programmatically?

Tags: android, textview

I'm having a hard time reseting the `maxLines` attribute of a `TextView` programmatically.

Just tried setting to `0` and it doesn't work. `-1` crashes the application. I could use a simpler workaround and set the `maxLines` to `5000` but I don't want to do that.

Any ideas how to do that?

*UPDATED*

Well, I've found one problem.. I've set the Ellipsize as well... I'm just going to use the following workaround:

```
TextView questionDetail = (TextView) mQuestionDetailHeader.findViewById(R.id.desc);

questionDetail.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getQuestion());
questionDetail.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //As in the android sourcecode
questionDetail.setEllipsize(null);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reset Android textview maxlines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413394/how-to-reset-android-textview-maxlines)

Answer (score 93):

As there isn't yet an approved answer - the proper way to reset the maxlines property of the TextView is:

`textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

As per [Valdemar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766150/valdemar)'s comment and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438524/740474). Using -1 will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Keep in mind only `END` and `MARQEE` setEllipsize() settings will be respected for maxlines >= 2 according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29):

> If setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, END and
>   MARQUEE* are only supported (other ellipsizing types will not do
>   anything).

Answer (score -2):

For setting the maxLines for a  text use mTextView.setMaxLines(0) or you have to programmatic-ally measure of the height text and multiply with the number of max line 
The result should set as the height of the textView

Answer (score -3):

if you want to have just a single line , then why don't you use:

```
    txtView.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: Not what I want... I need more lines... :(

Comment: then i think you can use setMaxLines().

Answer (score -6):

The `-1` should not crash your application. This actually what is used inside `TextView` by default:

```
case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_maxLines:
            setMaxLines(a.getInt(attr, -1));
            break;
```

This piece of code shows, that when `android:maxLines` is not specified, then code uses `-1` to set the value via `setMaxLines()` function.

---

I also made test application to verify my conclusions. And it works fine without crashing:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity
{           

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setMaxLines(-1);    
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm having an exception:  E/AndroidRuntime(10296): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
E/AndroidRuntime(10296):        at android.text.StaticLayout.getLineTop(StaticLayout.java:1240)
E/AndroidRuntime(10296):        at android.widget.TextView.getDesiredHeight(TextView.java:5472)
E/AndroidRuntime(10296):        at android.widget.TextView.getDesiredHeight(TextView.java:5443)
E/AndroidRuntime(10296):        at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:5412)

Comment: Just saw in the sourceCode

private void applySingleLine(boolean singleLine, boolean applyTransformation) {
 mSingleLine = singleLine;
 if (singleLine) {
  ...}
       } else {
            setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
            if (applyTransformation) {
                 setTransformationMethod(null);
        }
       }
     }
  
Actually the maxLines is Integer.MAX_VALUE. (setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); )

Comment: getting forece close if i use -1 in setMaxLines()

Comment: It does crash. I think this answer should be edited because it's misleading